# Melde's Experiment

Tags: waves

The conclusion of this  experiment is if the frequency of oscillation of a wave on a string is constant then  $p\sqrt{T}=\text{constant}$ where $p$ is the number of loops and $T$ is the Tension in the string.

Can somebody please give me the intuition to this? (No math formulae or derivations please!!)

Comment: Hi. Did you mean number of *nodes*?

Comment: @Gert It's actually number of loops I believe. Though there isn't too much of a difference, since $\text{Number of loops} = \text{Number of nodes} + 1$.

Comment: @Philip Yes, that tallies.

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody please give me the intuition to this?

Sure. Mathematically standing waves are described by the wave equation (check the link below for the meaning of all symbols):

$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=\frac{T}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}$$

where $y$ is the displacement.

[After a lengthy derivation](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284) (my work) we find that:

$$f=\frac{n}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\rho}}$$
For $n=1,2,3,...$

where $f$ is the frequency. Here, $n$ is your $p$.

So the frequency is proportional to:

$$\boxed{f\propto p\sqrt{T}}$$

For constant $f$:

$$p\sqrt{T}=\text{constant}$$

Comment: Thanks! , but I need the physics intuition ( i.e without mathematical formulae and derivations)....just a simple explanation/logic as to why it is that way

Comment: We do physics by means of math. THAT is our intuition, if you will. Demanding otherwise would be a bit like asking to explain Shakespeare with math.